# Launch app using dailpad and activity-alias

Tags: android

I'd like to launch a hidden app with dial pad . As the activity-alias has no java class, the following code is not working. Starting the normal activity is working fine. Can someone tell me how to start an activity-alias with dial pad?

```
public class MyOutgoingCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     // Extract phone number reformatted by previous receivers
    String phoneNumber = getResultData();
    if (phoneNumber == null) {
      // No reformatted number, use the original
      phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    }

         if(phoneNumber.equals("1234")){ // DialedNumber checking.
        // My app will bring up, so cancel the broadcast
        setResultData(null);

        // Start my app
        Intent i=new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("extra_phone", phoneNumber);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
         }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve figured it out right now. This code works:

```
public class MyOutgoingCallHandler extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Extract phone number reformatted by previous receivers
        String phoneNumber = getResultData();
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            // No reformatted number, use the original
            phoneNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        }

        if(phoneNumber.equals("1234")){ // DialedNumber checking.
            // My app will bring up, so cancel the broadcast
            setResultData(null);

            // Start my app
            Intent i = new Intent();
            String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(packageName,
                    packageName + "your_ALIAS_ACTIVITY");
            i.setComponent(componentName);

            i.putExtra("extra_phone", phoneNumber);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }

}
```